# How to respond to CA 2020 tax penalty notice? I forgot to indicate I had health coverage

Tags: tax-deduction, health-insurance, state-income-tax, california, penalty

I received this mail yesterday:

[PICTURE OF MAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFA16.jpg)

I am a student with F1 visa status and filed both federal and state taxes for 2019 and 2020. I do have an external scholarship that includes a very good health insurance. I filed 540NR for 2020 CA tax, and the filing instructions I followed did not say anything about line 91 (health care coverage checkbox), which I skipped. I believe they thought I don't have a health insurance and enforced the penalty on me.

Is there a way to go about this? Shall I contact my insurance or just amend my 540NR? I appreciate the help!

Comment: "or just amend my 540NR"?  That's what amendments are for...

Comment: "and the filing instructions I followed did not say anything about line 91 (health care coverage checkbox), which I skipped" Which instructions were you looking at? The [2020 540NR booklet](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2020/2020-540nr-booklet.html) clearly has instructions for line 91.

Comment: @user102008 the one given by the university. Looking at it now I can tell it was not updated and probably most students were not affected, only the ones with external insurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amend your taxes to calculate them correctly. Sign your amended return and send it off. Then attach a copy of the amended return to your response to the Notice you received.

Do all of this before the date of the deadline to respond to the Notice.

Comment: Don't forget to pay the balance as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I really appreciate it. To @R.Hamilton: thank you. But I don't know how much I really owe given that most of the penalty was for the health coverage. That is, I don't know how much I really owe when I subtract that amount. I will send them a mail or fax and see. Thank you again!

Comment: When you do your amended taxes, you will see how much you owe, if any. However you did your taxes the first time, do them again when amending, but check the correct box. Could look for "free tax filing help" locally if you need it. Here's a discussion of the checkbox issue in TurboTax tax software: https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/taxes/discussion/re-how-can-i-add-health-insurance-information-to-my-california-return-when-turbotax-forces-me-to/01/2003636/highlight/true#M722045  Here's the FTB guide to amending your return: https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/after-you-file/amend-a-return/index.html